# Google zone check SQL query level SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to check longitude latitude in SQL Server car in zone or not please help me.

Zone longitude below

```
  1 12426   1100    32.231389663    72.246093750    31.765537409    71.455078125    rectangle
```

Car longitude latitude

```
12426   31.966143862   71.806640625
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just a x1 >= x >= x2 && y1 >= y >= y2 check?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @g    geography,
        @pIn  geography,
        @pOut geography


DECLARE @minY varchar(10) = N'32.15701248607007'
DECLARE @maxY varchar(10) = N'69.78515625 '
DECLARE @minX varchar(10) = N'30.921076375384878'
DECLARE @maxX varchar(10) = N'67.78564453125'

SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((' + @minX + ' '  + @minY + ', ' + 
                                                   @maxX + ' ' + @minY + ', ' + 
                                                   @maxX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
                                                   @minX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
                                                   @minX + ' ' + @minY + '))', 4326);
SET @pIn = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(33.486435450999885 65.69677734375)',4326)
SET @pOut = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(  31.690781806136822 71.0595703125 )',4326)

SELECT Poly = @g, 
       pIn  = @pIn, 
       pOut = @pOut
SELECT DistanceInMetersIn  = @g.STDistance( @pIn ),
       DistanceInMetersOut = @g.STDistance( @pOut ),
       STIntersectsIn      = @g.STIntersects( @pIn ),
       STIntersectsOut     = @g.STIntersects( @pOut )
SELECT STIntersectionIn    = @g.STIntersection( @pIn ).ToString(),
       STIntersectionOut   = @g.STIntersection( @pOut ).ToString()
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly the following should work for you.  I would need you to provide sample script for data and desired results to be 100% sure.

```
Select *, -- Returns values for alias F if a match is found or else nulls for F.
        Case When F.ID Is Null 
            Then 'Not in a zone' 
            Else 'In a zone' 
            End InZoneIndicator
    From checkGeoFence C
    Left Join tblgeofencing F On C.Lat Between F.MinLatitude And F.MaxLatitude
                        And C.Long Between F.MinLongitude And F.MaxLongitude
```

Comment: this query not running ;9

Comment: its return every data car in zone

Comment: @AddiKhan - Then add a `WHERE` clause to pick out the one car you're interested it...